# Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 01 seconds - ERROR: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 3)

Tags: ruby, vagrant, chef-infra, hazelcast, ohai-gem

I am trying to run a simple Hazelcast cluster on Amazon EC2 following the  [official code sample](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/amazon-ec2-vagrant-chef), every step seems to be OK but when running `vagrant up --provider=aws` ( under the header "Let's do this thing" ) it fails as shown:

```
==> hazelcast2: - ohai (5.2.0)
==> hazelcast2: Installing Cookbook Gems:
==> hazelcast2: Compiling Cookbooks...
==> hazelcast2: [2017-10-24T20:03:06+00:00] INFO: The plugin path /etc/chef/ohai/plugins does not exist. Skipping...
==> hazelcast2: [2017-10-24T20:03:06+00:00] WARN: 
[DEPRECATION] Plugin at /tmp/vagrant-chef/ohai/cookbook_plugins/ohai/hint.rb is a version 6 plugin.     
Version 6 plugins will not be supported in Chef/Ohai 14. Please upgrade your plugin to version 7 plugin format. 
For more information visit here: docs.chef.io/ohai_custom.html
==> hazelcast2: 
==> hazelcast2: Running handlers:
==> hazelcast2: [2017-10-24T20:03:06+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
==> hazelcast2: Running handlers complete
==> hazelcast2: 
==> hazelcast2: [2017-10-24T20:03:06+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
==> hazelcast2: Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 01 seconds
==> hazelcast2: [2017-10-24T20:03:06+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
==> hazelcast2: [2017-10-24T20:03:06+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
==> hazelcast2: [2017-10-24T20:03:06+00:00] ERROR: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 3)
==> hazelcast2: [2017-10-24T20:03:06+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully 
(exit code 1)
==> hazelcast2: An error occurred. The error will be shown after all tasks complete.
An error occurred while executing multiple actions in parallel.
Any errors that occurred are shown below.

An error occurred while executing the action on the 'hazelcast1' machine. 
Please handle this error then try again:

Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the output above. 
Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.

An error occurred while executing the action on the 'hazelcast2' machine. 
Please handle this error then try again:

Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the output above. 
Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

/var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out:

```
Generated at 2017-10-24 21:36:55 +0000
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 3)
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/ohai-13.5.0/lib/ohai/dsl/plugin/versionvi.rb:27:in `initialize'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/ohai-13.5.0/lib/ohai/loader.rb:223:in `new'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/ohai-13.5.0/lib/ohai/loader.rb:223:in `load_v7_plugin'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/ohai-13.5.0/lib/ohai/loader.rb:93:in `block in load_additional'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/ohai-13.5.0/lib/ohai/loader.rb:90:in `collect'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/ohai-13.5.0/lib/ohai/loader.rb:90:in `load_additional'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/ohai-13.5.0/lib/ohai/system.rb:116:in `run_additional_plugins'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.5.3/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:119:in `compile_ohai_plugins'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.5.3/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:73:in `compile'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.5.3/lib/chef/run_context.rb:192:in `load'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.5.3/lib/chef/policy_builder/expand_node_object.rb:97:in `setup_run_context'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.5.3/lib/chef/client.rb:513:in `setup_run_context'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.5.3/lib/chef/client.rb:281:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.5.3/lib/chef/application.rb:291:in `block in fork_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.5.3/lib/chef/application.rb:279:in `fork'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.5.3/lib/chef/application.rb:279:in `fork_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.5.3/lib/chef/application.rb:244:in `block in run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.5.3/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:44:in `with_server_connectivity'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.5.3/lib/chef/application.rb:232:in `run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.5.3/lib/chef/application/client.rb:469:in `sleep_then_run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.5.3/lib/chef/application/client.rb:458:in `block in interval_run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.5.3/lib/chef/application/client.rb:457:in `loop'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.5.3/lib/chef/application/client.rb:457:in `interval_run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.5.3/lib/chef/application/client.rb:441:in `run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.5.3/lib/chef/application.rb:59:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.5.3/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:225:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.5.3/bin/chef-solo:25:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/chef-solo:58:in `load'
/usr/bin/chef-solo:58:in `<main>'
```

Ohai version:
    ohai -version
    Ohai: 13.5.0

Java jdk not installed (when it should be according to the receipt):

```
java -version
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-5-jre-headless
 * openjdk-8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.9-jre-headless
 * openjdk-9-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```

**Following the Stacktrace** I got to the point where I believe it has something to do with the fact that the function:
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/ohai-13.5.0/lib/ohai/dsl/plugin/versionvi.rb:27:in `initialize':

```
def initialize(controller, plugin_path, plugin_dir_path)
          super(controller.data)
          @controller = controller
          @version = :version6
          @source = plugin_path
          @plugin_dir_path = plugin_dir_path
end
```

... **requires 3 parameters and is called with only one in**: 
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/ohai-13.5.0/lib/ohai/loader.rb:223:in 'new'  in the function:
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/ohai-13.5.0/lib/ohai/loader.rb:223:in `load_v7_plugin'

```
 def load_v7_plugin(plugin_class)
      plugin = plugin_class.new(@controller.data)
      collect_provides(plugin)
      plugin
 end
```

I repeated the steps on an Ubuntu 14.04 and on an Ubuntu 16.04 VM and I am still stuck with the same Error, any idea what I am doing wrong?

P.S. I am just following the steps in the sample.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The important bit is probably this:

```
[DEPRECATION] Plugin at /tmp/vagrant-chef/ohai/cookbook_plugins/ohai/hint.rb is a version 6 plugin.     
Version 6 plugins will not be supported in Chef/Ohai 14. Please upgrade your plugin to version 7 plugin format. 
For more information visit here: docs.chef.io/ohai_custom.html
```

Figure out what is installing that plugin and check if anything is in the same folder and is an invalid plugin.